# Trying to make a list update in AJAX every certain time

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax

Here is the code I have but can not make update my page.

```
 setInterval(function getServer() {
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("1").innerHTML =      this.responseText;}

  xmlhttp.open("POST", "pedip.php", true);
  xmlhttp.send();    
  }, 30000)
```

Comment: what error message do you get in the browser **developer** tools console - or network tab

Comment: Paste your html code also to figure out seems like this function is working fine ajax call made on each timespan you defined **300000** issue seems like in your **pedip.php**